# How can I exactly solve a Quadratic Model with integer variables using DWave Ocean classical solvers?

Tags: optimization, d-wave, annealing, qubo

As an example, let's consider the following simple [`QuadraticModel`](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_dimod/reference/models.html#module-dimod.quadratic.quadratic_model) problem with just 3 `INTEGER` variables:

```python
from dimod import QuadraticModel

qm = QuadraticModel()

qm.add_variable('INTEGER', 'x', lower_bound=-2, upper_bound=5)
qm.add_variable('INTEGER', 'y', lower_bound=1, upper_bound=5)
qm.add_variable('INTEGER', 'z', lower_bound=-3, upper_bound=5)
for var in qm.variables:
    qm.add_linear(v=var, bias=1)

print(qm.to_polystring())
```

This code will print out the (actually linear) polynomial "energy" function $E(x,y,z) = x+y+z$ and the solution of the minimization problem in this trivial case would be $x=-2, y=1, z=-3$ (taking into account the bounds of each variable), with a minimal "ground state" energy equal to $-4$.

So my question is the following: how can I get this exact solution using DWave Ocean classical solvers? I tried to use the [`ExactSolver`](https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_dimod/reference/sampler_composites/samplers.html?_gl=1*1eof4fv*_ga*OTY0NzIxOTIxLjE2ODU5NDk0MTk.*_ga_DXNKH9HE3W*MTY4OTMzNjkyNi4zMi4xLjE2ODkzMzkzMTIuNDQuMC4w#exact-solver) class but it raises an error that I'm not sure to understand:

```python
from dimod import ExactSolver

solver = ExactSolver()
sol = solver.sample(qm)
```

```
TypeError: expected input vartype to be one of: Vartype.SPIN, 'SPIN', {-1, 1}, Vartype.BINARY, 'BINARY', {0, 1}, Vartype.INTEGER, 'INTEGER', Vartype.REAL, or 'REAL'; received .
```

If this is not supported, can I formulate and construct the same problem so that I can find the exact solution in a classical way? I would like to possibly stick with DWave software, but I'm also open to other approaches based on different tools.

Comment: Exact solver works with binary variables (-1,1) or (0,1). Your problem has discrete variables. Try looking into CQM and DQM solvers: https://docs.ocean.dwavesys.com/en/stable/docs_dimod/reference/sampler_composites/samplers.html